# How to rotate the navigation image according to the user direction in MKMapView?

Tags: ios, swift, mkmapview, mkannotationview

I would like to show the user's current location while toggling `Location` mode  on `Free Ride` in the Simulator. It's working fine, but take a look at the image below:

[image]

[image]

I want this image to rotate as the direction of the route changes. How can I do that? [Here](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0Bzk4QVQhnqKmM0x2Ti1saEhCUkk/view?usp=sharing) you can download the project. I have not implemented route on the below project, I only changed the arrow's direction towards the route.

Comment: I think you should access to the gyroscope and then adjust the rotation of the image accordingly.

Comment: Thanks for the comment..i have been waiting since days....i have no idea about that??

Comment: I have no idea, but 1) Isn't there a framework to integrate Apple's navigator in your app? 2) Try looking on Github, there're plenty of projects like this one. 3) I've edited your question, this might help getting more answers.

Comment: thanks a lot...can you provide me some links?

Answer (score 3):

If I understand your question correctly, you want your arrow to be aligned with the path drawn in the map, at every position on the path.

What I'd do is create a `CAKeyframeAnimation` with its path property set to the path on the map, and its `rotationMode` set to `kCAAnimationRotateAuto`. Add this animation to an image view containing the arrow.

Once you've added the animation, set the `imageView.layer.speed = 0` and control `imageView.layer.timeOffset` to move the arrow. This value goes from 0 to 1, and interpolates it to a position on the path.

CoreAnimation will now automatically rotate the view in a tangential direction to the path at every point.

Comment: yes..you knew that correctly....ok i will give a try..can you just do it in my demo project if you got some free time?

Comment: @copeME I'm sorry, I won't be able to do that. I believe I've explained this in a manner that should be easy to implement, however if you encounter a problem, feel free to ask.

Comment: sadly.. i still dont know how to implement this..i tried but couldnot???if you could help

Comment: @copeME where exactly did you get stuck?

Comment: sorry to say i dont know about CAKeyframeAnimation ...and how to use this..i googled a lot..couldnot get much help...thats why i put a bounty on this question :(

Comment: CAKeyframeAnimation *animation = [CAKeyframeAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
        animation.path = path;
        [view.layer addAnimation:animation forKey:@"position"];

Comment: can you explain me how to do this "Add this animation to an image view containing the arrow".?

Comment: My previous comment is exactly that.